# Solr backup and restore on Google cloud

Tags: solr, google-compute-engine

I have been struggling in getting solution for below scenario:

- I have 2 instances of solr cloud on composite engine.
- I have 2 instances of application rest api which calls above solr cluster for data.
- From my application I wanna take backup of solr and copy zipped backup file to google storage automatically and restore it automatically with the an url endpoint.

For that I am trying to make a api endpoint in my application that will call below solr api to take back up

```
admin/collections?action=BACKUP
```

And making another endpoint that call below url to restore

```
/admin/collections?action=RESTORE
```

However after taking backup my application doesnt have access to the back up files as they are getting saved on solr instances. So I am not able to save them to google bucket.

Please guide me a simpler way to achieve this i.e automatically backup and restore solr from other GCP instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered something like [gcs-fuse](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse)? It'll allow you to mount a GCS bucket directly on the file system.

You can then point the `BACKUP` command directly to the mount point for gcs-fuse on your Solr compute engine VMs, and the whole thing is abstracted away through how the VM is configured (instead of having to be manually uploaded afterwards with a separate tool when a local copy has been made).

Answer (score 0):

I found GCSFuse a bit unreliable, and decided to write a wrapper script which first detects the master for the given collection and then just executed the backup directly on that node.